# Apache POI version in ColdFusion 10

Tags: java, coldfusion, apache-poi, coldfusion-10

Is there a way of determining what version of Apache POI ColdFusion 10 uses? I have had a look in the lib directory but the name of the POI JAR file does not contain a version number.

If it is not the latest version how would I go about using the latest version in my code? I know I can use `this.JavaSettings` to load a JAR from a custom path.

I have downloaded the latest version of POI and it contains many JAR files: 6 in the top level directory, 4 in the lib subdirectory and 3 in the ooxml-lib directory. Do I need to reference all of these JARs within `this.JavaSettings`?

Also once I have referenced the correct JARs in `this.JavaSettings` how do I then use the library in my code? I have used ColdFusion's version of POI with code such as the following:

```
createObject('java','org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory').create(infile);
```

How would I need to change this code to use the latest version of POI which I referenced in `this.JavaSettings`?

Still getting my head around all this Java stuff! Thanks.

Comment: The last CF version I used was 8, but back then we used to just stop CF, delete the old POI jars and their dependencies, copy in the new ones (eg from the binary download), cross our fingers and start CF again! See the [POI components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) for what jars you need for what

Comment: I'd rather not mess with the JARs which ColdFusion functionality relies upon internally if this can be done using CF10's ability to load JARs from a custom location. That dependencies link looks useful though, thanks!

Comment: Here was one person's solution to upgrading the POI files - http://coldfusionexperts.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/issue-if-poi-jar-files-are-not-upgraded/

Comment: Edit: Hm.. on second read, it looks like *part* of this is a duplicate of the your other question [Using a newer version of Apache POI in ColdFusion 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524979/using-a-newer-version-of-apache-poi-in-coldfusion-10). Maybe close this one out and leave a link to the other half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar question more recently after forgetting I had already posted this question.

Please see [Using a newer version of Apache POI in ColdFusion 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524979/using-a-newer-version-of-apache-poi-in-coldfusion-10) which contains more helpful information.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps to know the version of any Jar

1. A jar is simply an archive file. Either extract the jar file to a directory (or use a tool like 7-Zip to view the contents without having to extract the individual files).
2. You will see a folder called META-INF
3. Inside META-INF there is a file called MANIFEST.MF
4. Open the manifest.mf file which contains details like version, vendor details etc.

Hope it helps

Comment: Good instructions. One suggestion: your typical jar can contain hundreds of class files - or more. Instead of extracting all files to disk, use a tool like 7-zip. It allows you to view jar contents, and the MANIFEST.MF file itself, without actually extracting everything to disk. You can do the same with the windows zip tool. You just have to make a copy of the file and give it a `*.zip` extension instead of `*.jar`.