# Using a newer version of Apache POI in ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, apache-poi, coldfusion-10

I would like to use newer version of Apache POI with ColdFusion 10 than the one with which it ships, as I need to access some of the newer functionality.

I have tried swapping ColdFusion's Apache POI JAR files for the newer versions but this causes some of the built in ColdFusion spreadsheet functionality to break.

Is it possible to load in the newer version for use in my code but leave ColdFusion's version untouched so that the built in spreadsheet functionality still works?

I know it is possible to [specify a custom Java load path in CF10](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffd.html) but if I try and load in a newer version of a library which has already been loaded for use by ColdFusion will this cause a clash?

Comment: Yes, I am also facing some Issue with new version of POI 3.10
CF 10 is not fully compatible with new version of POI. Only solution is to load it using custom java path, I am also working on it.
Let you know my findings.

Comment: Why don't you just give it a different name?

Comment: Please can you elaborate Dan?

Comment: *will this cause a clash?* No. In previous versions of CF, you could load a newer version of POI with the JavaLoader.cfc. Then use lower level java code, instead of the built in CF functions, to create and manipulate spreadsheets. The new CF10 feature is basically a rip of the JavaLoader, so it will work there as well. **NB:** You may need to omit the dom4j.jar (which is notorious for class loader issues).

Comment: Thanks Leigh, worked a charm. I used the latest beta version of Apache POI which does not require dom4j.

Comment: Cool. Might want to write up a brief summary of what you did (POI version, jars used, etc...) and post it as an answer. That will help the next guy.

Comment: Michael could you please check her
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553194/not-able-to-read-some-of-the-xlsx-files-shows-blank-page-coldfusion-10-poi
I am correct here or not regarding POI jar files inclusion in CF 10.

Comment: @sham - AFAIK, Michael is doing something entirely different. He is working with POI via `createObject()` and java code. That has absolutely no effect on the built in spreadsheet tags and functions. Those will still use the older version of POI, so it does not help you any. Not unless you want to use low level java code instead of the built in functions/tags.

Comment: @sham - Leigh is correct. I am not using CF's built in spreadsheet functions. I am using Apache POI directly using Java code. I need to be able to access a newer version of POI than the one which ships with ColdFusion because I need the new functionality. But I also do not want to break CF's spreadsheet functionality by replacing the POI JARs in the lib folder. My answer below is a solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use Mark Mandel's JavaLoader (https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader) to use a newer version of Apache POI with ColdFusion 10 without affecting CF's built in spreadsheet functionality.

I used version 3.11-beta2 of Apache POI because this does not depend on dom4j.jar which seems to be problematic.

I used JavaLoader instead of CF10's built-in ability to load JARs because this allows me to access ColdFusion's older version of Apache POI using `createObject()` whilst accessing the newer version stored in my webroot using the JavaLoader method `server[application.JavaLoader].create()`.

Comment: Good tip about dom4j. I did not know about that change: ["The OOXML jars used to require DOM4J, but the code has now been changed to use JAXP.."](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html).

Comment: ooxml-schemas has to be upgraded to a recent version, though! http://www.malcontentboffin.com/2014/07/18/Update-Apache-POI-Library-in-ColdFusion-10

Comment: @Bardware the instructions at that link describe how to replace CF's version of Apache POI with a newer version. My answer describes how to use a newer version without touching CF's version and therefore not affecting CF's built in spreadsheet functionality.